# Is there any video streaming online service that actually uses UDP?

Tags: tcp, network, udp, streaming, video

We usually hear that UDP is used with data with which a few packets loss/out-of-order can be tolerated like video streaming. And the instructor typically goes on saying "so if you lose a few datagrames, it'll not affect your video frame".

I've checked major streaming websites like youtube and others. And when I look in Wireshark, I can only see TCP (which is expected as it's a web server). No one is using UDP. I think when it comes to videos, UDP is used for like live conferences or so. But not for video streaming (which is typically hosted on a web server >> http >> TCP).

Could anyone clarify please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are essentially correct.  Mass-market services like YouTube rely on http because everyone uses a web browser to watch them.

If you have a special client, like a conferencing application, then you are more likely to see  UDP.